# Facebook login button open dialog with 8 digit code to enter instead of normal login

Tags: android, facebook

I am using facebook sdk for login and signup in my app. I've followed all steps given in below url:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android.
I am using latest facebook sdk version which is : **compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.31.0'**. So when I press continue with facebook login button I got a dialog which has 8 digit code along with QR code and it say's open facebook app and check for notification or enter this code to facebook.com/device. Is this new login flow by facebook or I am doingsome mistake while configuring the sdk?.

Comment: That sounds like Login for Devices, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/for-devices But I can’t see how one could implement that “by accident”, and the documentation section you are referring to doesn’t even mention it.

Comment: @CBroe when I was trying to click facebook login button provided by sdk it gives me error: IllegalArgumentException: No client id is provided.

Comment: That sounds like you forgot to specify the app id in the manifest ...

Comment: No I've added appid inside manifest.